# Exception Mapping - org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: exception.DenemeException: off bu exler

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a restful application that imports some contacts to database. I want to throw exception when a file is not uploaded via restful. so i write an exception class DenemeException, and i want to send status 404, when i run code i get this error org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: exception.DenemeException: off bu exler
can u help me pls?

DenemeExceptionMapper.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;




@Provider
public class DenemeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<DenemeException> {
     @Override
 public Response toResponse(DenemeException ex){
     return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity(ex.getMessage()).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
 }

}
```

DenemeException.java

```
public class DenemeException extends Exception {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public DenemeException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

}

My Rest Controller

```
@POST
@Path("/import")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
public String saveContacts (@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response,
         @QueryParam("alt") String alt) throws DenemeException {

    byte[] content = null;

    FileItemStream item = null;
    try{
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        item = iterator.next();
        if ("fileUpload".equals(item.getFieldName())){

            content = IOUtils.toByteArray(item.openStream());

          }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("hata oldu");
        throw new DenemeException("off bu exler");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the ExceptionMapper using the Application , eg

```
public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet();

    public HelloWorldApplication() {
        // ADD YOUR RESTFUL RESOURCES HERE
        this.singletons.add(new SimpleServiceImpl());
        this.singletons.add(new AuthenticationServiceImpl());
        this.singletons.add(new DenemeExceptionMapper());  //<<< -- HERE IS YOUR EXCEPTION MAPPER !
    }

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return this.empty;
    }

    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return this.singletons;
    }
}
```